# Loading Rails partially to run a spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

Currently I'm writing a unit test a method which the only thing that I need from Rails is to use the url helper methods, like **'product_url'**

I really don't want to load the whole Rails environment, as we all know it's a bit expensive, just to be able to run the url helper methods.

Is that a way of loading only part of Rails environment, just the necessary to run these methods?

Thanks!
Alex

Answer (score 0):

As far, as I know it is not so easy. But you can use [spork server](https://github.com/sporkrb/spork) to have rails testing environment in memory to make your tests run fast and smooth.

Answer (score 0):

I'm with @Nick_Kugaevsky– in fact, I'm a lot more negative than him. I just don't think it's possible. To have the concept of a helper, Rails has to load ActionPack, which is not very useful by itself. I guess you could figure out a way to work directly with ActionPack, but I'd be extremely surprised if that were possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to mock all `*_path` in your tests.